# Has anyone found good data sources to model / backtest crypto-currency trading strategies?

Tags: data, bitcoin

I want to write trading strategies for crypto-assets. I am looking to find data sources I can play with to backtest. Has anyone found easy to use data or do I have to index / crawl data sources?

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicate? In the related post, there are no references on how to get any cryptocurrencies...

Comment: https://bitcoincharts.com/ has charts and you can download the data as well.

Comment: Duplicate is unjustified. Linked answer has no sources of crypto-currency data as the OP requested. Such would be available on several places. Often the different crypto exchanges have APIs that provide a lot of data for backtesting. E.g. https://poloniex.com/support/api/. For an overview of exchanges refer to e.g. https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/volume/24-hour/ . Full backtesting frameworks are available as well for crypto assets, e.g. https://cryptotrader.org/.